# VSTS plugin development - Disable parsing env vars in string input

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm developing an extension to VSTS. The tasks are written in JavaScript.

In the extension, there is a string input field. In this input, the user can enter a path in his file system. The user can use the agent's environment variables, such as `${'Build.SourcesDirectory'}`. During the task, I read the input variable by `getInput()` function of `vsts-task-lib/task` library.

The problem: I need to get the raw string input in order to process it during the task. For example, instead of `c:\agent\_work\1\s` i'd prefer to get `${'Build.SourcesDirectory'}`.

This is the input field in
task.json:

```
{
  "name": "myName",
  "type": "multiLine",
  "label": "My Label",
  "required": true,
  "properties": {
    "resizable": "true",
    "rows": "10",
    "maxLength": "10000"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you have to use $ in front of `Build.SourcesDirectory` which will auto parsing env vars, as a workaround, you could use some other symbol such as #, if you need the $ , then replace the # to $ later.

Comment: I have to use the conventional way of using environment variables, i.e. ${'Build.SourcesDirectory'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable value is replaced by the system as soon as the build start. So getInput() method can only get its value rather than the original string. If you do want that strings, call the Rest API to parse the build definition settings.